# How to simulate the hover with keyboard events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, typescript

I have the following HTML template in which the list items are dynamically added to the dropdown list.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown" (keydown)="triggerTraverse($event)"></button>
    <fa-list-filler>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items [class.active]="checkItem(item,selectedItem)">
            <span (click)="doNavigate()" class="cookie"></span>
        </li>
    </fa-list-filler>
```

I have the following hover style for the list items:

```
li > .cookie {
        cursor: pointer;
        &:hover{
            background-color: 'yellow';
        }
    }
```

When I hover these list items with my mouse, I can see the hover style applied to the list item i.e., I can see the yellow color background color in this case.

By default, the first item is selected i.e., it has class active. Then, when the user presses the down arrow key, the active class remains at the same place, but the hover state should move down to the next list item and so onto the next item and should wrap around.

I implemented the following method but I am unable to proceed correctly with the subsequent elements.

```
triggerTraverse(evt: KeyboardEvent){
   if(evt.keyCode === 27){
    closeDropdown();
}else if(evt.keyCode === 40){
    let initialEle = document.querySelector('li.active');
initialEle.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.classList.add('hoverstyle');
}
}
```

hoverstyle is an another class which I just implemented to add the backgroundcolor to the element.

```
.hoverstyle{
 background-color: 'pink';
}
```

could anyone please help.

Comment: do you see the class  `hoverstyle` added to the `li` in the inspect element?

Comment: yes. But that only happens for the second element only as I am not doing anything further to traverse through the whole list.

Comment: Kul, answer this, if the logic says start from `li.active` (ur 1st element) and then move down, will it actually go beyond the second element ?

Comment: No. It doesn't! It is just stuck on second element in this case!

Comment: thats exactly the point. Its always doing it from the top most element li.active, in the current logic. So everytime u press rhe down key the next element is always the 2nd element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the selected index and use the `ngClass` directive.

For example:

template:

```
<input ... (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">
<div *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index;"
     (mouseover)="highlight(i)"
     [ngClass]="{'selected': i === selectedIndex}">
    <span>{{ option }}</span>
</div>
```

component:

```
selectedIndex = 0

...

highlight(i: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = i;
}

onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.code === 'ArrowUp' && this.selectedIndex > 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.selectedIndex--;
    } else if (event.code === 'ArrowDown' && this.selectedIndex < (this.options.length - 1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.selectedIndex++;
    } 
}
```

css:

```
.selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I am facing one problem though, when there are lot of elements in the dropdown, the elements don't come into view when I keep traversing the list with down or up arrow. How can I achieve that? Any hints?

Comment: This works...

@ViewChild("scroll") scroll: ElementRef;
    
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollIntoView(false);
    }